# Running WampServer using a QPushButton

Tags: qt, wampserver, qprocess, qpushbutton

i am trying to run wampserver using a QPushbutton :
when i click on a QPushbutton i have a SLOT runnig

```
    void LoginFenetre::lancerWampServer(){
//QProcess::startDetached("\"G:/Games/3DM-dhredgoyear/Launcher.exe\"");
    QString wampPath = "C:\\wamp\\wampmanager.exe";
    QProcess *wamplauncher = new QProcess();
    wamplauncher->start(wampPath);
    //QProcess::startDetached("C:\\wamp\\wampmanager.exe");//second solution 
}
```

neither the first or the second solution is woking
when i tryed with launcher.exe or any othe . exe file its warking but it doesnt work with wampserver

Comment: try using forward slashes in the path to exe file ("C:/wamp/wampmanager.exe")

Comment: still doesnt work thanks anyway :P

Comment: connect the `QProcess::error(QProcess::ProcessError error)` to a slot and try to get error message for debugging